# NotImplementedError when running model.fit in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am currently working on Human Action Recognition on Aeriel Videos. I am using this [dataset](https://okutama-action.org/). You can see the [videos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11du4LdRP_ELreeWyh49sQNs-YEdHB_dt?usp=sharing) and [labels](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6P22dHlA2MTLVdnaG93c3NFNGc?usp=sharing) file. I am building an SSD model to train the data..

I am getting an error while using model.fit.

I think the main problem is in the DataGenerator Class though I am not able to resolve the error. The code is given below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import json


class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
   def __init__(self, img_dir, ann_dir, 
                batch_size=32, dim=(300,300),
                shuffle=True):
       self.idx_to_name = ["None", '"Handshaking"\n', '"Hugging"\n', '"Reading"\n', '"Drinking"\n', '"Pushing/Pulling"\n', '"Carrying"\n', '"Calling"\n', '"Running"\n', '"Walking"\n', '"Lying"\n', '"Sitting"\n', '"Standing"\n']
       self.name_to_idx = dict([(v, k) for k, v in enumerate(self.idx_to_name)])
       self.img_dir = img_dir
       self.ann_dir = ann_dir
       # self.frame = frame
       self.batch_size = batch_size
       self.dim = dim



   def _get_annotation(self, file, j):
       
       frame_map = dict()
       with open(file, 'r') as fp:
           line = fp.readline()

       while line:
           line_split = line.split(' ')
           frame_id = int(line_split[5])
           if line_split[10] is not None:
               label = line_split[10]
           else:
               label = "None"
           val = (int(line_split[0]), list(map(int, line_split[1:5])), list(map(int, line_split[6:8])), line_split[10])
           if frame_id not in frame_map:
               frame_map[frame_id] = [val]
           else:
               frame_map[frame_id].append(val)

           line = fp.readline()
   
       for obj in frame_map[int(j)]:
           xmin = float(obj[1][0]) / 3840.0
           ymin = float(obj[1][1]) / 2160.0
           xmax = float(obj[1][2]) / 3840.0
           ymax = float(obj[1][3]) / 2160.0
           name = obj[3]
           boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

           labels.append(self.name_to_idx[name] + 1)

       return np.array(boxes, dtype=np.float32), np.array(labels, dtype=np.int64)

   def __getitem__(self, index):
       start_index = index * self.batch_size
       x_train = []
       y_train = []
       i = start_index - 1
       while len(x_train) < self.batch_size:
           try:
               for i in os.listdir(self.img_dir):
                 for j in os.listdir(self.img_dir + '/' + i):
                   img = cv2.imread(self.img_dir + '/' +i + '/' + j)
                   img = cv2.resize(img,(320,240))
                   img = np.array(img, dtype = np.float32)
                   img = img / 255.0
                   boxes, labels = self._get_annotation(self.ann_dir + '/' + i + '.txt', int(j[:-4]))
                   x_train.append(img)
                   y_train.append(boxes)
                   i += 1

           except Exception as err:
               print(err)
               continue
           
       x_train = np.array(x_train)
       y_train = np.array(y_train)
 
       return x_train, y_train
```

```
train_data = DataGenerator("/content/okutama_imgs", "/content/okutama_labels", batch_size=4)
```

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss= SSD_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, epochs = 50, verbose = 1, callbacks = callbacks)
```

This error occurs when running the model.fit. I don't understand why this is happing, if you need any more information I would be happy to give it to you. Here is the error

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-7c278c6b3232> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_data, epochs = 50, verbose = 1, callbacks = callbacks)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in __len__(self)
    456         The number of batches in the Sequence.
    457     """
--> 458     raise NotImplementedError
    459 
    460   def on_epoch_end(self):

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: This error is because you have not implemented some function in the inherited class, which in this case I think it is ``__len__`` function.

Comment: Hi, Did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates you have not implemented some needed function in the inherited class, which in this case it is `__len__` function.

Add `__len__` function to your `DataGenerator` class like this:

```
def __len__(self):
    #len(self.x) is the length of your input features
    return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)
```